# ASP.NET MVC 3 file upload via JSON model

Tags: javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

My web application interacts with the server-side (ASP.NET MVC 3) by posting JSON data
to certain URLs (without using html forms).

How can I post file to the server and bind it to `HttpPostedFileBase` using JSON and without using multipart forms?

Thanks!

Comment: As far as I'm aware you can't HTTP won't allow you to post files unless you use multipart forms.

Comment: I can post the file as a binary string as one of the models properties...

Comment: How do you access the file? How do you turn the file into binary? JavaScript has no local file access.

Comment: I'm using HTML5 File API FileReader.

Answer (score 2):

I have done this but did not use the `HttpPostedFileBase` to get the content from the MVC app. I simply used JSON.

You can simply use the `FileReader.onload` (on HTML5) method to extract the file content and post as a Base64 string directly to the MVC controller. The `#upload-button` is an `<input type=file ...>` tag.

```
    var file = $('#upload-button')[0].files[0];
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (function (f) {
        return function (e) {
            if (e.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) {
                $.ajax("FileStore/SavePicture", {
                    data: { content: e.target.result, name: f.name },
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json"
                });
            }
        };
    })(file)
```

From there you can use `Convert.FromBase64String` method to conver to a `byte[]`. This is how the Action content look like;

```
    string base64String = content;
    // Get the starting point of the actual content from the base64String.
    int start = base64String.IndexOf(",") + 1;
    int length = base64String.Length - start;
    contentAsString = base64String.Substring(start, length);

    byte[] dataAsBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(contentAsString);
```

There might be some other ways of doing this.

Comment: Yes, I did that but there is another problem. In fact, I'm using JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize the JSON and base64 string is not deserialized automatically to HttpPostedFileBase property.Perhaps, there is any attribute which could be applied to the HttpPostedFileBase property of the model so that I could customize deserialization process for this certain property?

Comment: Yes, didn't work for me either. So I used this approach instead as a work-around solution.

Answer (score 0):

It could be done, but you will have cross-browser problems, more details you can find here: [How can I upload files asynchronously with jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/166221/how-can-i-upload-files-asynchronously-with-jquery) OR just google "ajax file upload"

Comment: IE is what, 70% market share, if it's not supported by IE, what's the point?

Comment: @Liam Everything depends on project, also he could check for support, if not make normal submit.